# Why don’t Ashkenazim say korbanot before mincha?

Tags: tefilla

Why doesn’t nusach ashkenaz say the korbanot before ashrei in mincha, like nusach sefard and Sefardim do? Especially since we say it before shacharis, so why not by mincha too?

Comment: This question is easily turned around: "Why do nusachim besides Ashkenaz say the korbanot again before mincha? Especially since they say it before shacharit, so why duplicate it by mincha too?"

Comment: @magicker72 the "especially" doesn't follow/is separate? The korban/ketoret mentioned in that section was associated with (offered at both) shacharit and mincha (Taanit 27b for more info)

Comment: @magicker72 as Rabbi Kaii says, you can’t flip the question because the Tamid was given in both shacharit and mincha.

Comment: The Rama (the quintessential ashkenazi rabbi) says to say Tamid before Mincha. I say it. Maybe your information is just wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's just ashkenazi communities that are inclined to say hecher shmoneh esrei at mincha and daven mincha gedola as their go to practice (many times doing hecher at mincha gedola?!)  are the ones that skip it, rounding out their mincha foibles.

Comment: @DoubleAA basciallly every nusach ashkenaz Siddur I’ve come across starts at ashrei…

Comment: @CuriousYid interestingly, the nusach Ashkenaz artscroll Siddur for Eretz Israel has korbanot before mincha

Comment: @CuriousYid Not everything said is in every siddur and not every siddur contains everything said.

Comment: @CuriousYid If you have additional information to back up your question, please include it in your question post, not in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

The dirshu mishna berura has a note on סימון מ"ח that the reason the minhag didn't take hold (like קרבנות of שחרית) is due to the fact that we see from יחזקאל that the תמיד של בין הערבים wont exist לעתיד לבא.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Tzaff and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Hey, would you mind explaining the context in yechezkel and why this would be that the mincha tamid will no longer exist?

Comment: Aside from the highly questionable historicity of this claim, why does that alleged premise justify skipping it before לעתיד לבוא?

Comment: @DoubleAA you'd have to ask the Dirshu folks; don't shoot the messenger.